# installing application in /system/app directory in android

Tags: android, installation, system

Generally when we install android applications, they go in the `/data/app` directory, which holds user applications. But `/system/app` directory holds the system applications like Browser, Gallery, Email etc.

So,i want my application to be installed in the `/system/app` directory.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: You'll need root access on the phone to do so.

Comment: yes i know that but i need to develop app for rooted device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to this if the phone is not rooted, or you are not flashing your own custom rom to a device.